# Multiple Else Statement Logic in SQL

Tags: sql, if-statement

Hi I have a question on using multiple else statements without re-using if statements.

```
If FieldA = '14'
     Set FieldX = '1'
Else If FieldB ='15'
     Set FieldX = '2'
Else If FieldC = '16'
     Set FieldX ='3'
Else
     Set FieldX = '10'
```

My question is, say both FieldB = 15, and FieldC = 16.  So the last two conditions are satisfied but the first isn't.   Does the line stop as soon as the Else statement is met?  Or will it continue to the next Else statement to test for fieldC?

Comment: 1. That's not SQL. 2. You could easily test it yourself. 3. There is a hint in the word *else*.

Comment: Please identify which DBMS you're using.  What you show is not a standard SQL, though it could easily be part of the language some DBMS supports.  As to your question, the way that such statements work in most languages is that the first term that evaluates to true executes the corresponding action and terminates the overall `IF` sequence.  So if `FieldB = '15'`, `FieldX` will be set to `'2'` and not to `'3'`.

Comment: It's quite simple. If the condition is met, then there's no reason to do the ELSE. If you want to change which value is returned, then just change the order of the evaluations.  Btw, in an actual SQL statement a [CASE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_case.asp) is often used for such logic.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Yes the FieldX will be '2' you can read it here how if and else if work[`if and elseif`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_if_then_elsif.htm)